# creating a remote repo of powershellgallery.com - is this possible?

Tags: powershell, nuget, artifactory

Has anyone tried to or know how to setup a remote or cached repo within Artifactory for the powershellgallery?

I am unable to find anything even remotely talking about this online as well.

PSGallery URI is:  https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2

I am beginning to think it was intentionally made by MS to not allow situations like that (but am looking for confirmation if that's the case)

NOTE: the intent here is that we will then have an internally accessible remote repo that is a copy of the PSGallery.  Which then allows us to make sure we are scanning the modules and abiding by compliance regulations.

when it's added to Artifactory as a remote repo, its successful, but is empty.

Then, we set it up on Windows machine with `register-PSRepository -Name psgallery-remote -SourceLocation myartifactoryuri` (successful)

But when trying to do a `find-module -name InvokeBuild -repository psgallery-remote` it fails with no results.

When doing `find-module -name InvokeBuild -Repository PSGallery` it's successful.

Comment: @CJVanderlinden - did you get this working? I'm running into the same issue where `Find-Module` and `Install-Module` don't return anything. My remote repository is configured with the settings in the accepted answer already. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should configure Artifactory remote repository as the following :

- Url: https://www.powershellgallery.com/
- NuGet Download Context Path : api/v2/package
- NuGet Feed Context Path: api/v2

Link for JFrog documentation on NuGet Remote Repositories : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/NuGet+Repositories#NuGetRepositories-RemoteRepositories